# Is it possible to have a templated, single-parameter sum function in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, sum, generic-programming

In python, we can do this:

```
int_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sum(int_list)) # prints 15
float_tuple = (1.2, 3.4, 9.9)
print(sum(float_tuple)) # prints 14.5
```

The `sum` function takes any iterable of elements that know how to be added to each other and to 0 and produces the sum.

I wanted to make an identical function in C++11. I'm aware that there exists the `accumulate` method, but I want a function that takes a single parameter. Essentially, I want to know how to make the following code compile:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>

template<typename iterable>
auto sum(iterable iterable_) {
    auto it = iterable_.begin();
    auto end = iterable_.end();
    if (it == end) {
        return 0;
    }
    auto res = *(it++); 
    while (it != end) {
        res += *it++;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> int_vector = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
    std::cout << sum(int_vector) << '\n';    // prints 15
    std::deque<int> int_deque = {4, 5, 7};
    std::cout << sum(int_deque) << '\n';     // prints 16
    std::list<float> float_list = {1.2, 3.4, 9.9};
    std::cout << sum(float_list) << '\n';    // should print 14.5, but produces error.

}
```

This code *almost* works. The issue is that `auto` sees the `return 0;` in the case that the iterable is empty and it assumes that the function must return an `int`. Then it sees that the `float` version returns a `float` and it gets confused. Is there any way to tell the compiler to, say `return float(0)` if it sees that the `return` later on returns `float`?

Comment: Replace `return 0` with `return {}`?

Comment: Aside: `sum` takes a *copy* by value of the iterable rather than a reference to it.

Comment: @kfsone, I was unaware of this. I thought Python objects (at least in CPython) were passed as PyObject*? You mean that the entire list is copied into memory for the sum function? That seems horribly inefficient.

Comment: @lerenard You're passing by value -- passing by value incurs a copy.  Basic C++ stuff.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, of course. I was under the impression @kfsone was referring to *python's* sum function. The correct way to remedy this would be to change it to `auto sum(iterable* iterable_)` or `auto sum(const iterable& iterable_)`?

Comment: Why not just wrap `std::accumulate`? I believe that proposed ranges library has such a wrapper. But not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make this work at least for standard containers.

A standard container defines a type alias named `value_type` for the type of value stored in that container. For an empty container, you can return a value-constructed object of this type:

```
template<typename iterable>
auto sum(iterable const &iterable_) {
    auto it = iterable_.begin();
    auto end = iterable_.end();
    if (it == end) {
        return typename iterable::value_type();
    }
    auto res = *(it++); 
    while (it != end) {
        res += *it++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This does depend on the contained type being default-constructible, but that's probably not a major problem (certainly works for primitive types like `int` and `float`).

Comment: That works! It makes sense that the container knows what type of object it stores. I'm glad that is exposed to the user so that we can take advantage of it!

Comment: To support raw arrays you can use the freestanding `std::begin` and `std::end`, and `decltype` instead of `iterable::value_type()` (which doesn't exist for a raw array). Also, I'd just declare the return type directly, using `decltype`. Then `return 0;` would suffice. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want something to work with *any* C++11 range (that is, anything that you can iterate over in a range-based for expression - including arrays as well as containers that have free `begin` and `end`), we can just add some using-declarations and wrap `std::accumulate`

```
template <class Range>
auto sum(Range&& range) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(*begin(range))>;

    return std::accumulate(begin(range), end(range), T{});
}
```

If you don't want to wrap `accumulate`, then you can just re-implement that loop as well to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach works even with non-standard containers; as long as something implements `begin()` and `end()`, in a reasonable way.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename iterable>
auto sum(iterable && iterable_) {
    auto it = iterable_.begin();
    auto end = iterable_.end();

    typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*it)>::type value_type;

    if (it == end) {
        return value_type(0);
    }
    auto res = *(it++);
    while (it != end) {
        res += *it++;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::list<float> float_list = {1.2, 3.4, 9.9};
    std::cout << sum(float_list) << '\n';    // works now.
}
```

Comment: With `std::begin()` (or `cbegin`) instead of `.begin()`, this ought to work on arrays as well because of the `typedef` you introduced.